# (Git) Push a previous commit to a new repository without losing current changes

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've been developing an application. As the application scales up, it's common sense to create my own code base to re-use in the future, so I don't have to do everything all over again.
I've created a completely new repo named MyCodeBase. Now **I want to push a specific previous commit, to this new branch, without losing any changes (unstaged files & unpushed commit)** I've already made to the current repository. Is this task possible?
What I've tried:

```
 git push MyCodeBase <commit_SHA>:HEAD:main
```

> (error: src refspec <commit_SHA>:HEAD does not match any)

```
git push MyCodeBase HEAD <commit_SHA>:main
```

> (error: The destination you provided is not a full refname)
> We tried to guess what you meant by:
>
> - Looking for a ref that matches 'main' on the remote side.
> - Checking if the  being pushed ('<commit_SHA>')   is a ref in "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
>   refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side. Neither worked, so we
>   gave up. You must fully qualify the ref. hint: The  part of the
>   refspec is a commit object. hint: Did you mean to create a new branch
>   by pushing to <commit_SHA>:refs/heads/main

```
git push MyCodeBase <commit_SHA>:main
```

> error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,
> starting with "refs/"). We tried to guess what you meant by:
>
> - Looking for a ref that matches 'main' on the remote side.
> - Checking if the  being pushed ('<commit_SHA>')   is a ref in
>   "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
>   refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side.
>
> Neither worked, so we gave up. You must fully qualify the ref. hint:
> The  part of the refspec is a commit object. hint: Did you mean
> to create a new branch by pushing to hint:
> '<commit_SHA>:refs/heads/main'? error:
> failed to push some refs to
> 'https://github.com/<my_user_name>/MyCodeBase.git'

Summary:

- Have: Current repository with uncommited changes. A blank repository
- Want: Push a previous commit to the blank repo, without losing uncommited changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

What you want is the `git push repository refspec` syntax, with the *`refspec`* being something along the lines of:

```
a123456:refs/heads/main
```

Be sure you know precisely what this does (i.e., read the long section).

## Long

First, before you get too deeply into the details, remember that the definition of a Git repository is—more or less<sup>1</sup>—a *collection of commits*.  Git isn't really *about* changes, or files, or branches, or any of many of the things that we do with it, at the root level: at that level, it's about *commits*.

This mans you need to know precisely what a commit is and does for you, and that boils down to just a few things:

- Each commit stores a full snapshot of some set of files.  These aren't changes, these are snapshots.  They're analogous to a tarball or zip file.  If you were to download and unpack an archive like this, you would not think of it as "changes".  You could download *two* archives and *compare* them to find changes, of course.  In the same way, you should not think of a Git commit as changes—but if you have *two* commits and *compare* them, you can *find* changes.
- Meanwhile, each commit also stores some *metadata:* some information about the commit itself.  This includes a name and email address, and a date-and-time stamp, for the person who made the commit.  (In fact, it has two of these sets of data: one for the author, and one for the committer.)  It has an arbitrary *log message* that whoever makes the commit gets to write, to tell people later *why* that particular commit exists.  And—crucially for Git—each commit has some number of *parent commit hash IDs* stored inside it.
- Each commit has a unique hash ID.  When I say [*unique*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique), I don't mean *a little unique*, either.  I don't even mean "very unique", which is in some ways a misuse of the word.  Git has, as a sort of goal, the idea of giving *every* commit *anyone ever makes anywhere* a hash ID that is peculiar to *that one commit*.<sup>2</sup>
- No part of any commit can ever be changed, once it's made and has acquired its unique hash ID.

This unique hash ID, and the unchanging nature of a commit, means that one Git can always tell whether some other Git already has the *same commit*, or not, just by having the two Gits exchange *hash IDs*.  They need not exchange the entire set of files, or even some subset of the files.  The hash ID alone tells the entire story.

In this way, the hash ID *is* the commit, in a sense.  You either have the hash ID, in which case you have the commit, or you don't, in which case you find some Git—any Git anywhere—that *does* have that hash ID and get the commit from them.

What `git push` and `git fetch` are about, then, is making sure that the *receiving* Git—for `git push`, that's the "other" Git; for `git fetch`, that's *your* Git—has some or all of the *commits* that the *sending* Git wishes to send.

---

<sup>1</sup>I will touch on the "more or less" part as well in a moment.

<sup>2</sup>Git is allowed to fail in this goal as long as the two Git repositories in which some non-unique hash ID occurs never actually *meet*.  But rather than try to guess which repositories might exchange data with each other, and which never will, Git tries to just make each commit hash ID universally unique.

---

#### Git doesn't "like" stand-alone commits

The "Git philosophy", as it were, is that you always have, at all times, *all of the history* of a repository.  But what exactly *is* the history of a repository?

If we look at the definition of a commit again—an archive plus metadata, with the metadata including the raw hash ID of the *parent or parents* of a commit—we can pretty quickly draw a picture of what this could mean:

```
first-commit  <-... <-commit  <-commit  <-commit  <-... <-last-commit
```

Each of the "arrows" coming out of a commit, here, is really the *hash ID* of the *earlier* commit.  We say that the later commit *points to* the earlier commit.

The actual hash IDs are random-looking, and also very large and ugly and impossible for humans to remember,<sup>3</sup> so for drawing purposes, I like to use uppercase letters to stand in for the hash IDs:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
```

This is a drawing of a small repository with just three commits in it.  It also has only one *branch name*, `main`.  The *name* `main` serves to let Git know which of the three commits is the *last* one.

Obviously, in a tiny repository like this, we could just look at all three commits.  One—commit `A`—doesn't point back at all: it's the very first commit, and it can't.  One points to `A`, and that must be the second commit that we're calling `B`, and the last one points to `B`, so that must be the last commit of the three.  But in a really big repository, there may be many thousands of commits.  Finding the "last" one would take too long, and has other drawbacks.  So Git adds *branch names*, and other names such as tag names, to the mix.  This is what makes a repository *more or less* a collection of commits: It's really a collection of commits **and some names** by which we *find* some particular commits.

Branch names in particular find the *last* commit of a branch.  This is also how we *add* a commit to a repository.  If we're on `main`, and have:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

and we add a *new* commit, the new commit gets some random-looking, big ugly unique hash ID, which we'll call `D`.  Inside `D`, the metadata includes the hash ID of the *current* commit `C` (which we, or Git, found by the name `main`).  So new commit `D` points back to existing commit `C`.  Now, in order to make commit `D` the *last* commit of this branch, Git simply *writes `D`'s hash ID*, whatever that is, into the name `main`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

and now we have more commits on our branch.

If we instead add a *new* branch, we might start out with this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main, develop
```

If we're `on branch develop`, as `git status` would say, and we run `git commit` and make a new commit `D`, Git makes the new commit in the same way as always, but this time the *branch name* that Git writes into is `develop` instead of `main`, producing:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

Note that, for Git to do anything *useful* with commit `C`, like show what *changed* in it, Git needs commit `B` as well.  To make commit `D`, Git needs commit `C` first.  In general, Git wants and needs *every historical commit* starting from the end-points—whose hash IDs are in the various branch names—and working backwards to the very first commit.

What this means in general is that in most Git repositories,<sup>4</sup> you have *every commit leading up to the last ones*.  These commits *are* the history, in a Git repository.  There is no such thing as "file history": each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, as a sort of archive.  The history *is* the set of commits, which Git finds by starting at the ends—from the branch names—and working backwards.

---

<sup>3</sup>This is all necessary in order for them to be universally unique.

<sup>4</sup>Git supports so-called *shallow* repositories, where the history cuts off at some point, but in general, you do not want to use these.

---

#### What this means for your `git push`

When you run `git push`, you are telling your Git to send some particular commit to some other Git repository.  The syntax for this is:<sup>5</sup>

```
git push <repository> <refspec>
```

The <repository> part here can be a URL, or the name of a *remote* such as `origin`.  Using a name adds various convenience features.  Git will find the URL using that name, for instance, which avoids having to type the same long and error-prone URL repeatedly.<sup>6</sup>

The real magic is in the <refspec> part.  A *refspec* **can** be:

- a branch name, by itself; or
- a raw commit hash ID, followed by a colon, followed by a *reference name*; or
- the word `HEAD`, followed by a colon, followed by a *reference name*;

or several more options, most of which I won't go into here.  You're trying to use the middle or last option, and when using these last two options, the *name* often has to be a *fully qualified reference name*.  We'll get back to this in a moment, but before we do, let's look at what `git push` will do:

- Given the hash ID, or the name `HEAD`, your Git will look up the corresponding commit.
- Your Git will then offer that hash ID to the other Git.  If they already have that commit, they will say, to your Git: *No thanks, I already have that one.*  This has some implications.
- If they *don't* have that one, your Git must now offer that commit's *parent commit hash IDs*.  Most ordinary commits have just the one hash ID; merge commits have two or more; and root commits have none.  Whatever the commit's type is, your Git is obligated to offer *all* the parents.

This repeats until they finally say that they do have the hash IDs, or your Git runs out of commits to offer because you've offered every historical commit leading up to and including the one you're pushing.

This allows your Git to know which files of yours *their* Git already has.  That's the implication I mentioned above.  If you offer commit `C`, and they *don't* have that, but then you offer commit `B` and they *do* have that, this tells your Git that they have commits `B` *and* `A` both, and therefore they have all the *files* that exist in commits `B` and `A` already.  So your Git can now compress your commit `C`, knowing that they have commits `A-B` already and thus referring to the files in those existing commits.

Of course, if they don't have those commits—for instance, if this is a new, totally-empty repository—your Git will have to send *every commit leading up to the final one you're sending*.

Once this is all done, your Git now asks their Git to set one of *their* names.  Let's finish off this section now, and describe *reference* properly.

---

<sup>5</sup>There is more than one syntax; this is the general one that you'll need here.

<sup>6</sup>Using a remote name adds more convenience features than just this URL-shortening one, but that's all I will cover here.

---

#### Reference names

I mentioned above that Git uses each *branch* name to store the hash ID of the *last* commit we want to say is "on the branch", but also that Git has more than one kind of name.  The other kinds of names include tag names, remote-tracking names, the "stash" that handles `git stash`, and many more.  The three kinds of names that you, as a user, normally deal with are *branch* names, *tag* names, and *remote-tracking* names like `origin/main`.

Each of these names lives in a [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  Branch names, in particular, live under `refs/heads/`, while tag names live under `refs/tags/`.  This means that the *branch* `main` is really the *name* `refs/heads/main`.  The *tag* `v1.2` is really `refs/tags/v1.2`.

Most of the time, when you run `git push`, you are asking your Git to send commits from one or more of your *branches* to some other Git, and when you do that, you want them to set one of *their* branches to remember the *same last commit*.  When you're doing that with, e.g.:

```
git push origin main
```

or:

```
git push origin develop
```

you generally want them to set their branch of the same name.  So here, Git lets you leave out the `refs/heads/` part *and* the colon *and* the entire other part.  Your Git figures out that `main` really means `refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main`.  That is, you want your branch name, `main`, to determine the *last* commit you'll send, and you then want your Git to ask their Git to set *their* **branch** name `main`, too.

You, however, want to use a raw hash ID.  Your Git doesn't know, then, whether it should ask their Git to set a *tag* name, or a *branch* name, or some other kind of name entirely.  What you need to do is use a fully-qualified name:

```
git push <url-or-remote> <hash>:refs/heads/somebranch
```

This will ask their Git to *create or update* a *branch* name, `somebranch`, in their Git repository, to remember as its *last* commit, the commit whose hash ID you used in the `git push` line.  It will have the side effect of sending that commit *and all of its history* if necessary.

#### You literally cannot push uncommitted changes

Note that when you run `git push`, what your Git sends are *commits*.  It sends the commits—the snapshots with metadata—to the other Git, which then stores them in a quarantine area for a moment.  Your Git does not send *changes*, but rather whole commits.<sup>7</sup>  Your Git then asks their Git to create or update some *reference* name—branch name, tag name, or whatever other kind of name you like—so as to remember the specific commit you named in your `push`.

If you have uncommitted code, this stuff is *not in Git*.  Your Git literally *can't* send it yet.  To send it, your Git would have to commit it first.<sup>8</sup>  But you will be sending the entire history of commits up to this point to your other repository.  If that's what you want—often, it is—you're all good: go for it.

---

<sup>7</sup>Your Git does use compression, which may turn the whole commit into changes across the push operation—but these changes, if any get constructed, depend on what commits *their* Git has, that your Git knows about.  Their Git may need to re-expand these and then re-compress them later, depending on many factors.

<sup>8</sup>It's possible to make temporary commits that are not on any branch, of course; your Git could then send those.  Such temporary-commits-not-on-any-branch are how `git stash` works, for instance.  But Git does not do this today, and the receiving Git would need to use *some* name to remember them, which means we're right back to the whole refspec issue.